# Circleci task job never executer

Tags: yaml, circleci

I'm having the following circleCi config :

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    machine: true
    branches:
      ignore: gh-pages
    steps:
      - run: echo "Skipping tests on gh-pages branch"
  deployment:
    machine:
      node:
        version: 6.11.2
      npm:
        version: 3.10.10
    branch: ci
    steps:
      - run: git config --global user.email "<GITHUB_USERNAME>@users.noreply.github.com"
      - run: git config --global user.name "<YOUR_NAME>"
      - run: echo "machine github.com login <GITHUB_USERNAME> password $GITHUB_TOKEN" > ~/.netrc
      - run: cd website && npm install && GIT_USER=<GIT_USER> npm run publish-gh-pages
```

that aims to deploy a https://docusaurus.io/ site on my github page.

Actually, when the CI runs on the `ci` branch, it should run the `deployment` job.

Actually, the `deployment` job is never triggered and I don't understand why.

**I'm well building my ci branch**

Here's my circleci build :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not running correctly because the config you are using is completely incorrect. There's aspects of CircleCI 2.0 configuration and aspects of CircleCI 1.0 configuration.

I'd recommend choosing one platform (CircleCI 2.0) and then going through the configuration reference for that version. Here's the configuration reference for CircleCI 2.0: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/

Feel free to do that, come back and update your question, or post a question at https://discuss.circleci.com.

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI